# Trying to Scrape Freddie Mac Website using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get the data attributes from the table on the following webpage:

https://freddiemac.mbs-securities.com/freddie/details/31334W2C4

When I run the code I receive a 'Runtime Error 91: Other variable or With block variable not set'

```
Sub Data_Pull()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTML As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    XMLPage.Open "Get", "https://freddiemac.mbs-securities.com/freddie/details/31334W2C4", False
    XMLPage.send

    HTML.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    net_interest_rate = HTML.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item")(2).innerText

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = net_interest_rate  

End Sub
```

Comment: Please reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help formulating a question. Your 'question' seems to be lacking an actual question. It's helpful that you have provided the work that you have done, however, you have not included the problem you are experiencing (such as any errors/exceptions).